# I'm designing a plugin to create database indexes. Suggestions?

Tags: plugin-development, database, performance, optimization

I'm starting a (totally open-source) little project to create a WordPress plugin that will add appropriate indexes to WP's MySQL tables to improve performance. (Some wp tables, notably wp_postmeta and wp_usermeta, can use better indexing.)

My goal: make larger sites (with more posts, users, and so forth) perform better.

What is the worst-performing database table in WordPress? And, what makes it perform badly?

Please answer this question with any feedback.

If you know of some other project that makes mine unnecessary, let me know about that too please.

(I have enough development, testing, and database skills to know what I'm getting into with this project.)

Comment: If this isn't an appropriate question for wpse, please let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't a forum so you need to word the question so that it's specific and you can mark an answer as not just the most useful response, but as the correct factual answer for all people with this question for all time

Comment: This is a bit tricky because it the most cumbersome table will usually depend on what the site is being used like.  Interesting project though.  Do you have a GitHub for it so I can follow along?  I do see the benefit of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm aware of the audacity (foolishness ???) of trying to make software that claims to optimizae millions of sites.  :-)  I'm shooting for stuff that will help at least some sites first time around ...  No github yet, but I will let you know. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Interesting. How would "appropriate indexes for the WP's MySQL tables to improve performance" look like?

Comment: The proposed package would, on activation, would tell the database to `CREATE INDEX blablah ON wp_somethingmeta(col, col, col)` for indexes that help common queries on bigger sites.  It would then do a little measurement, with the installing user's permission of course. (Deactivating it would remove the extra indexes. ) The adding of appropriate indexes is very important to database scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin, [Index WP MySQL for Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/), is released.  GPLed [source code](https://github.com/OllieJones/index-wp-mysql-for-speeed) is here.

Anecdotal experience shows speedups on some big WP and WooCommerce sites.

Here's the data definition language it runs to create useful [compound indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD UNIQUE KEY meta_id (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (post_id, meta_key, meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP KEY post_id;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP KEY meta_key;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, post_id);
 
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD UNIQUE KEY umeta_id (umeta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, meta_key, umeta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP KEY user_id;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP KEY meta_key;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, user_id);
 
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD UNIQUE KEY meta_id (meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (term_id, meta_key, meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta DROP KEY term_id;
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta DROP KEY meta_key;
ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, term_id);
 
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD UNIQUE KEY option_id (option_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_options DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY (autoload, option_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_options DROP KEY autoload;
 
ALTER TABLE wp_posts DROP KEY type_status_date;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY type_status_date
                     (post_type, post_status, post_date, post_author, ID);
ALTER TABLE wp_posts DROP KEY post_author;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY post_author
                     (post_author, post_type, post_status, post_date, ID);
 
ALTER TABLE wp_comments ADD KEY comment_post_parent_approved
                     (comment_post_ID, comment_parent, comment_approved, comment_ID);
```